# Meteor.js + ScrollMagic TweenMax.to

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, scrollmagic

Trying to get Meteor template.rendered working for ScrollMagic
this is the code i wish to get it working.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    scrollMagicController = new ScrollMagic();

        Template.StartAnimation.onRendered({
        // Create Animation for 0.5s
        animation: function () {
           var tween = TweenMax.to($('#animation'), 0.5,
                {
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 39, 46)',
                    scale: 5,
                    rotation: 360
                })                                
        }
    });
})}
```

Pkg Dependency
hipstersmoothie:scrollmagic  0.0.9

This is based on a tutorial made by [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-interactive-scrolling-websites-with-scrollmagic-js).
and the first part of the code [codepen](http://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/JodjPP)

Trying to recreate the magic in meteor. I'll be grateful if someone could have a look at these codes.

Thank you.

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Found another solution by referencing [Using greensocks with meteor](http://www.codedisqus.com/7NHNWWeWqX/using-greensock-with-meteor.html)

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Meteor.startup(function () {


    scrollMagicController = new ScrollMagic();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Create Animation for 0.5s
        var tween = $(".animation");
        TweenMax.to(tween, 0.5,               
            {
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 39, 46)',
                scale: 5,
                rotation: 360
            });
    });
```

Which works !! Still I ponder on how to use it properly with blaze... 
In the mean time, i will try to finish the code for the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 Template.StartAnimation.onRendered(function() {
   // use this.$() to have jquery only search the dom in the current template scope
   var $e = this.$('#animation'); 
   var transforms = {
     backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 39, 46)',
     scale: 5,
     rotation: 360
   };
   var tween = TweenMax.to($e, 0.5, transforms)
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't think that this:

```
Template.StartAnimation.onRendered({....});
```

is up to date.

I use the following for things that should happen, when template is rendered.
It's similar to your $(document).ready(function(){...}); but it triggers only for this specific template.

```
Template.StartAnimation.rendered = function(){
  //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Template.onRendered() ist the up-to-date method to hook up code after the template has rendered. It allows you to have multiple onRendered callbacks per template instead of just one - Template.rendered = func() is outdated